# how come scala code gets compiled with Java?

Tags: java, scala

I'm trying to understand how Scala code works with Java in Java's IDE. I got this doubt while working with Spark Java where I saw Scala packages too in code and using respective classes and methods.

My understanding says, Scala code need Scala's compiler to convert into Java.class files and then from their onwards JDK do its part in JVM to convert into binaries and do actions. Please correct me if am wrong.

After that, In my spark Java project in eclipse, I couldnt see anywhere where scala compiler is being pointed.

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <!-- <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId> <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId> 
                </exclusion> </exclusions> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Avro Messages -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-avro_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spark MLLIB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.janino/janino -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!--Spark java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/janino/InternalCompilerException -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.16</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
                <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.16</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>  
</project>
```

And for example am using below import of scala in my Java class file. But literally not getting Idea from which Jars its picking and where its getting compiled to Java.class for further processing.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters;
```

Can anyone please help me to understand this unknown magic to me ?

Comment: Compiled .class files do not need their original compiler/library producer (scalac, other vendor's javac, python).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependencies ship in class file form. That `JavaConverters` class must indeed be compiled by `scalac`. However, the maintainers of janino have done this on their hardware, shipped the compiled result to mavencentral's servers, which distributed it to all mirrors, which is how it ended up on your system's disk, which is why you *do not* need `scalac` to use it.

Comment: so you mean to say "the scala code which is required to convert scala code into Java.class files" people from janino  have done already in their machines and placed in java jar and given out to people like me to use it. So whenever ever I see the scala imports in my spark java project, is the scala code but in Java compiler's compatible form. Does it makes sense ? I think am still not able to imagine completely

Comment: @Oxana Yes. You write code in some language, a compiler then turns that into class files which is a 'common language' (scala code is turned by scalac into class files. java code is turned by javac into those same class files, etc) - and then a JVM (`java.exe`) executes these class files. Which means `java.exe` doesn't need to care in which language it was written.

Comment: Imagine we decide to write a book in Esperanto together. You only know French, I only know Dutch.  I write my part (in dutch), get it translated, we put it in the book in Esperanto. You write your part (in french), get it translated, also goes in the book. Someone who buys the book just needs to be able to read Esperanto. They probably don't even realize that chapter 1 was originally written in Dutch and chapter 2 in French. Maven gives you the translated book, meaning, no need for you to have a dutch->esperanto translator.

Answer (score 0):

The jars, they have compiled files only. They will not have the source files. If you are using any dependency, it is not the source, it is compiled output. So, in your case, `JavaConverters`, is compiled too. And it is from the package `scala.collection` which is a built-in package.

May I know you have Scala installed on your system?

Comment: You must have Scala installed on your system because JavaConverters is a Scala built-in one. Of course, you don't need scalac here because JavaConverters is part of Scala SDK. For ex: Will you compile ArrayList again? No, right? Even if you search for ArrayList.java in jdk, you can't find it. It will be compiled file, ArrayList.class.